# Notify upon background jobs finishing running in bash

Tags: bash, background, notify

I am running some time-consuming executables with different parameters assigned in a loop as background jobs in parallel. Here is a toy example and its output:

```
bash-3.2$ set -o notify
bash-3.2$ for (( i=0 ; i < 4 ; i+=2 )); do
>    sleep ${i} &
> done
[1] 32394
[2] 32395
bash-3.2$ [1]-  Done                    sleep ${i}
[2]+  Done                    sleep ${i}
```

Notice that when each job finishes running, it will notify me. In the finishing message the command of the job will be shown, but in the way that the parameter is not expanded, so there is not obvious way to tell what parameter value it is using by looking at the message. What I hope the message is like

```
bash-3.2$ [1]-  Done                    sleep 0
[2]+  Done                    sleep 2
```

Is it possible to do so?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

**Not very pretty:**

```
for (( i=0 ; i < 4 ; i+=2 )); do
    sleep ${i} && echo  -en "\nsleep ${i} "&
done
```

Output looks like:

> [1] 29311
>   [2] 29313
>
> sleep 0 [1]-  Done                    sleep ${i} && echo -en "\nsleep ${i} "
>   user@host:~$
>   sleep 2 [2]+  Done                    sleep ${i} && echo -en "\nsleep ${i} "

**A function could neaten it up a bit:**

```
myeval () {
    eval "$*" && echo -en "\n$* "
}
```

Then you can do:

```
for (( i=0 ; i < 4 ; i+=2 )); do
    myeval "sleep ${i}"&
done
```

and the output looks like:

> [1] 29635
>   [2] 29636
>
> sleep 0 [1]-  Done                    myeval "sleep ${i}"
>   user@host:~$
>   sleep 2 [2]+  Done                    myeval "sleep ${i}"

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to wait till the last one is done..

```
for ((i=0; i < 4; i+=2 )); do
    long_running_process $i &
done

wait
```

Each long_running_process (assuming its a shell script) can print out a status message and its own $1 immediately before termination.

Comment: But then he doesn't get the immediate feedback that `set -o notify` gives him.