# How to get a stdout message once a background process finishes?

Tags: bash, unix, background, stdout

I realize that there are several other questions on SE about notifications upon completion of background tasks, and how to queue up jobs to start after others end, and questions like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795446/how-to-be-notified-when-a-scripts-background-job-completes), but I am looking for a simpler answer to a simpler question.

I want to start a very simple background job, and get a simple stdout text notification of its completion.

For example:

```
cp My_Huge_File.txt New_directory &
```

...and when it done, my bash shell would display a message. This message could just be the completed job's PID, but if I could program unique messages per background process, that would be cool too, so I could have numerous background jobs running without confusion.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: `bash` on my Mac already tells me when a background job is done.  Has that changed in more recent versions?

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** user000001's answer separates commands with `;`. I separated commands with `&&` in my original example. The only difference I notice is that you don't have to surround your **base** command with braces if you use`&&`. Semicolons are a bit more flexible, so I've updated my examples.

The first thing that comes to mind is

`{ sleep 2; echo "Sleep done"; } &`

You can also suppress the accompanying `stderr` output from the above line:

`{ { sleep 2; echo "Sleep done"; } & } 2>/dev/null`

If you want to save your program output (`stdout`) to a log file for later viewing, you can use:

```
{ { sleep 2; echo "Sleep done"; } & } 2>/dev/null 1>myfile.log
```

Here's even a generic form you might use (You can even make an alias so that you can run it at any time without having to type so much!):

```
# dont hesitate to add semicolons for multiple commands
CMD="cp My_Huge_File.txt New_directory"
{ eval $CMD & } 2>/dev/null 1>myfile.log
```

You might also pipe `stdout` into another process using `|` in case you wish to process output in real time with other scripts or software. `tee` is also a helpful tool in case you wish to use multiple pipes. For reference, there are more examples of I/O redirection [here](https://superuser.com/a/436594).

Comment: Can you please specify where I would place my command in your answer?

Comment: ex: `{ cp My_Huge_File.txt New_directory; echo "Copy complete!"; } &`

Answer (score 2):

You could use command grouping:

```
{ slow_program; echo ok; } &
```

or the wait command

```
slow_program &
wait
echo ok
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect, especially the command grouping method, but after I receive the "OK" message, I have to press enter to clear the command! This is a minor complaint, I know, but if a background process finishes while I'm furiously entering commands, I can foresee this could interrupt things. Any way to make it simply print the echo message without requiring user input?

Comment: @jake9115 It doesn't really require use input, but it echoes the output after the prompt is printed, so it appears that you have no prompt. You can just enter the next command without hitting enter

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way is to simply have the output from the background process go to a temporary file and then consume the temporary file.

When you have a background process running it can be difficult to capture the output into something useful because multiple jobs will overwrite eachother

For example, if you have two processes which each print out a string with a number "this is my string1" "this is my string2" then it is possible for you to end up with output that looks like this:

> "this is mthis is my string2y string1"

instead of:

```
this is my string1
this is my string2
```

By using temporary files you guarantee that the output will be correct.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will not be trying to print the output to stdout for this very reason, but just want a message letting me know the process completed.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment above, `bash` already does this kind of notification by default, as far as I know.  Here's an example I just made:

```
$ sleep 5 &
[1] 25301
$ sleep 10 &
[2] 25305
$ sleep 3 &
[3] 25309
$ jobs
[1]   Done                    sleep 5
[2]-  Running                 sleep 10 &
[3]+  Running                 sleep 3 &
$ :
[3]+  Done                    sleep 3
$ :
[2]+  Done                    sleep 10
$
```